# call a flash function from javascript function and not button

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using this code to call a actionscript 3 function through javascript

http://www.viget.com/inspire/bi-directional-actionscript-javascript-communication

and I want to call the acrionscript 3  function from a javascript function, but not on a button action.

how do I do that?
thanks!

actionscript code:

```
//call to javascript
ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript");

//call from javascript
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionscript", callFromJavaScript);


function callFromJavaScript(dir):void 
{
  if(dir == 'right')
  {
    var tweenR = new Tween(box, 'x', None.easeNone, box.x, 145, 1, true);
  }
  if(dir == 'left')
  {
    var tweenL = new Tween(box, 'x', None.easeNone, box.x, 23, 1, true);
  }
}
```

javascript code:

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
  var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
  return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}

function callToActionscript(str) 
{
     getFlashMovie("nameOfFlashMovie").sendToActionscript(str);
}
```

html button

```
<form action="javascript:callToActionscript('asjs', 'left')" id="form1">
            <input type="submit" value="&lt;--" />
        </form>
```

I tried calling it like this in the body but it didn't work:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">     
 callToActionscript('asjs', 'left');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript isn't failing, but you are passing two strings into the `callToActionscript` function, and it expects only one.  The result of this is that you are sending the string "asjs" into Flash, and since your `callFromJavascript` function expects only "left" or "right", it does nothing.

Try it with just the value you want to pass:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    callToActionscript('left');
</script>
```

Also, you don't need the `language="javascript"` in your script tag. You've already given the language as part of the mime type.

Answer (score 1):

```
function callToActionscript(str) 
{
     getFlashMovie("nameOfFlashMovie").sendToActionscript(str);
}
window.action = callToActionscript('left');
```

Hope you are expecting this.